Is it possible for a matrix to have only the zero vector as an eigenvector?
Say I have a normal matrix $M$, operating on vector space $V$, which has eigenvalues $\lambda_1, ..., \lambda_n$. Define $A_1, ..., A_n$ to be projectors onto the orthogonal complements of $\lambda_1$-eigenspace, ..., $\lambda_n$-eigenspace respectively.
Then if I take matrix $A_n(A_{n-1}(...(A_1(M)A_1)...)A_{n-1})A_n$, would I be correct in saying that this matrix has only the zero vector as an eigenvector?
I have seen various sources online that state that the zero vector is not an eigenvector however, so does that mean this matrix has no eigenvectors at all? The responses to similar questions all refer to the idea that while a matrix may not have any real eigenvectors that arise from solving the characteristic equation, it may have complex eigenvectors and as such it is not possible for a matrix to have only $\vec{0}$ as an eigenvector. However in this case I'm not able to use those responses to come up with a valid non-zero eigenvector for the matrix defined above.
I note that this matrix would be the $0$ matrix if the sum of all $\lambda_i$-eigenspaces were equal to the vector space $V$, as then any vector $v \in V$ could be written as a linear combination of eigenvectors of $M$, and thus the matrix would send all $v \in V$ to $0$, but I'm not sure how to prove that $V = \lambda_1\text{-eigenspace} + ... +  \lambda_1\text{-eigenspace}$ either.
Any help would be appreciated.

In general the sum of all eigenspaces is not equal to $V$. If this is true, there exists a basis of eigenvectors and the matrix is diagonalizable. So this is not "provable", since it does not hold generally

The definition I know of eigenvector is some $v\ne 0$ such that there is some $\lambda\in \Bbb F$ such that $Av=\lambda v$. So technically $0$ should never be an eigenvector. Be as it may, if the field is algebraically closed then all matrices have eigenvectors. If the field is not algebraically closed, and say $p\in\Bbb F[x]$ is monic without roots, then by taking a matrix $A\in \Bbb F^{\deg p\times\deg p}$ such that $\det(x I-A)=p(x)$ you obtain a matrix without eigenvectors.

@BrakkoFTW: thanks for the comment. In this case the matrix $M$ is normal so it's diagonalisable — then can I take the fact that the sum of all eigenspaces is equal to $V$ as a given?

@tikis.tacos, in that case you can. In fact, allowing a basis consisting of eigenvectors is sometimes even taken as the definition of a diagonalizable matrix

TLDR: The zero vector is never an eigenvector, and you just wrote down the zero matrix (in which every vector is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $0$).
Perhaps a simplified example of your set up, let's just consider $\mathbb{R^2}$. Consider $P_x$ the projection onto $x$ and $P_y$ the projection onto $y$. Then we can write down matrices for these transformations as
$$P_x=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\0&0
\end{bmatrix}$$
and $$P_y=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
This would correspond to the case your eigenspaces are the $x$ and $y$-axes. Then if you just compute $P_xP_y$ it will be the zero matrix in which every vector is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $0$ as
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 0 &0\\
0&0\end{bmatrix}v=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}=0v.
$$

Thanks for the response Steven. I note that in your example, the sum of the eigenspaces is equal to the overarching vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$ — if I know that $M$ is normal and thus diagonalisable, can I take that the sum of all of its eigenspaces is equal to the overarching vector space as a given fact?

This should be true for finite dimensional vector spaces, look at the spectral theorem. But it doesn't matter with the matrix you construct since the important thing is that the eigenspaces are orthogonal, so after two projections into orthogonal directions you get the zero matrix.

Ah understood — because $\mathbb{R}^2$ is 2-dimensional, you can only do two orthogonal projections before reaching $0$, and in my case because $V$ is n-dimensional, inevitably after $n$ orthogonal projections we get the $0$ matrix. Thanks for the clarification.

No even after two orhtogonal projections in $\mathbb{R}^n$ you will end up getting the zero map.

I see, I mixed up an orthogonal projection with a projection onto orthogonal complement -- 2 orthogonal projections making the $0$ map makes sense as the action of the second projector on whatever is the result of the first projection must necessarily be 0 if the projectors are orthogonal. Say instead that I have define projectors that project onto the orthogonal complements of the axes, then in this case $n$ of these projectors stacked together would make the $0$ matrix for an $n$-dimensional space.

For example, if I define $P_{\perp x}, P_{\perp y}, P_{\perp z}$ as the projectors onto the orthogonal complements of the $x, y, z$ axes. Then any $2$ of these projectors doesn't necessarily equal $0$, but stacking all 3 together would turn every vector to $0$ -- similarly, if I define $P_{\perp 1}, ..., P_{\perp n}$ as projectors that project orthogonally away from each other, then stacking them all together inevitably sends every $n$-dimensional vector to $0$.
